# Visual Studio doesn't recognize Docker installation

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

I am working with Docker in Visual Studio 2017. Up to this week, everything worked fine, I could create, run and debug my containers. 
Yesterday i was in the situation where i saw myself required to reinstall Docker, Hyper-V and Visual Studio.

Now Docker works just fine on its own, which means i can build and create containers from Powershell as usual. But the Visual Studio integration fails. Each time i want to launch a project in a Container, it just throws an error stating it did not find the corresponding container. It doesn't matter if Docker runs or not, its always the same error message.

My suspicion is that VS somehow still tries to refer to the "old installation", which does not exist any more, and therefor does not look for the new one. I have observed that the new installation was still customized and also still knew which projects where loaded the last weeks, therefore it doesn't seem too fresh to me.

Is there any way to reinstall VS2017 in a way that it is an **absolutely** fresh installation, that doesn't remember anything from the past?
Or is there an easier way to fix this?

Comment: The thread [Cannot start Docker debug with VS2017 15.3](https://github.com/Microsoft/DockerTools/issues/37) has many suggestion, which worked for some but not others. Try all of them, and hopefully one will work.

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, but a nice workaround:

I just installed VS2019, so now i have VS2017 and VS2019 both on my machine.
If I create a project with docker support in VS2019, it debugs fine, **even in VS2017**.

There is probably something wrong with the way my VS2017 creates docker supported projects. 
Therefore, if you are having the same issue, simply create your projects in another compatible version of VS, and you should be fine.